# Обработка исключений при работе с паттерном MVCS

Tags: java, mvc

Имеется в виду архитектура вида Model-View-Controller-Service. Каждый слой может выбрасывать исключения, и есть несколько вариантов их обработки:

- отлавливать каждое исключение на своём уровне;
- отлавливать, логировать и перебрасывать его же на следующий уровень;
- не отлавливать, а сразу пробрасывать исключение на следующий уровень,
  и так до контроллера, который будет формировать нужный статус код и
  тело ответа в зависимости от типа исключения.

Что выбрать в такой ситуации?

Возможно, на этот вопрос нельзя дать однозначного ответа, однако, я уверен, что существуют удачные и проверенные практики решения проблемы, которыми опытные участники сообщества могли бы поделиться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хорошая практика:

На каждом слое ловить исключение(1) и кидать дальше другое(2), которым обернуть первое(1). И так вплоть до контроллера

Делается это потому что следующие слои не должны по сути знать о другом слое и быть максимально изолированными

См. Пример

```
Service(Catch DBException -> Throw new ServiceException(DBException))
Contoller(Catch ServiceException -> Throw new ControllerException(ServiceException))
и тд
```

Comment: "обернуть" - значит добавить стек-трейс прошлого исключения в исключение уровня выше?

Comment: да. Сделайте свои исключения с конструкторами, которые принимают в параметры Throwable. Тогда стек-трейс будет включать всю информацию прошлых исключений

Comment: понял, а как тогда реализовать разные ответы контроллера под разные ошибки, если все исключения будут в итоге обёрнуты в один и тот же тип?

Comment: В этом нет нуждны. Моожет быть 2 варианта: 1) Ошибку можно исправить и вы делаете это в секции catch. В таком случае дальше исключение швырять нет смысла. 2) Ошибку исправить нельзя и вы даете юзеру сообщение, что приложение останоило работу. Не стоит выводить ему сообщение по типу "Data base connection refused" или "Null pointer exception occurred". Давайте ему что-то общее пот типу "Error occurred" на любую ошибку. Ему не будет разницы, приложение все равно рухнула

Comment: @coolsv, если помог, отметь плиз как правильный ответ

Comment: спс за помощь, я до завтра подожду, если ничего лучше не ответят, то отмечу как правильный, без проблем